# How to describe an OLAP cube to Mondrian

Tags: business-intelligence, olap-cube, mondrian, kylin

does anyone have a working example of Mondrian connected to Kylin? 
I would like also to know if there are tools which are able to build the XML OLAP cube description in an automatic fashion.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no such tool yet. There is a blog about Saiku with Mondrian connect to Kylin. http://kylin.apache.org/blog/2019/05/23/saiku-kylin-molap/